# Only see 3 textarea field on Plugin Setting Page

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, settings

I am developing the plugin to send user difference confirmation email which more than 20. I put those fields in templates/settings.html so that the admin could change and update the message content. However, after I put more 3 textareaFields, I only able to see 3 Textarea display on the setting page. The 4th one does not show up. Does anyone know how to solve that issue? Thanks

[image]

```
{{ forms.textareaField({
    label: "Customer Account Creation Confirmation Message"|t,
    instructions: "Customer email message when customer register" |t,
    name: 'custAccountCreation',
    value: settings.custAccountCreation,
    rows:5,
})}}

{{ forms.textareaField({
label: "Customer Account Appointment Confirmation Message"|t,
instructions: "Customer email message when customer appointment confirmed" |t,
name: 'custApptConfirmed',
value: settings.custApptConfirmed,
rows:5,
})}}

{{ forms.textareaField({
label: "Customer Appointment Reminder with Vet Identification"|t,
instructions: "Customer Appointment Reminder with Vet Identification" |t,
name: 'custApptReminder',
value: settings.custApptReminder,
rows:5,
})}}

{{ forms.textareaField({
label: "Customer Appointment Reminder with Vet Identification1"|t,
instructions: "Customer Appointment Reminder with Vet Identification1" |t,
name: 'custApptReminder1',
value: settings.custApptReminder1,
rows:5,
})}}
```

Comment: If you scramble them up, do you still only get the first 3? Or is there something specifically wrong with that 4th one?

Comment: Thanks @LindseyD. After I shuffle the textareaField, I found that the 4nd one is misspelled in defineSettings() under the EmailUserPlugin.php

Comment: Excellent! Would you mind posting that as an official answer?

Answer (score 2):

After shuffle all textareaField, I found the 4th one custApptReminder1 misspell in function defineSettings() at my plugin.php. After corrected it, the field is show up.

```
protected function defineSettings()
    {
        return array(
            'custAccountCreation' => array(AttributeType::String),
            'custAccountCreationSubject' => array(AttributeType::String),
            'custApptReminder'=> array(AttributeType::String),
            'custApptReminder1'=> array(AttributeType::String),
        );
    }
```